# C String Null Zero?

Tags: c

I have a basic C programming question, here is the situation. If I am creating a character array and if I wanted to treat that array as a string using the %s conversion code do I have to include a null zero. Example:

```
char name[6] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
printf("%s",name);
```

The console output for this is:

```
abcdef
```

Notice  that there is not a null zero as the last element in the array, yet I am still printing this as a string.

I am new to programming...So I am reading a beginners C book, which states that since I am not using a null zero in the last element I cannot treat it as a string.

This is the same output as above, although I include the null zero.

```
char name[7] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','\0'};
printf("%s",name);
```

Comment: This is where some security vulnerabilities come from.

Comment: +1 I like null zeroes :) "What kind of zero was that?" "A null zero." "A long zero." "A floating zero." "A double zero." ...

Comment: In general, the way you would do this is `char name[7] = "abcdef"` (the string literal in ""s automatically includes the NUL)

Comment: Just using `7` instead of `6` in the declaration also initializes `name[6]` with `0`.

Comment: @Jens: nice, I didn't know that, I wasn't sure about it but I checked and it's stated at §6.7.8.21 + §6.7.8.10. However, I wouldn't make use of this feature, it's not immediately clear to someone who reads the code for the first time that the non-explicitly initialized elements are automatically initialized to zero.

Comment: @Matteo: yes, usually I wouldn't use it either, but *if* you'd put the length in the declaration, then you even may do it like this. The version I'd use which is the least error prone is `char name[] = "abcdef";` There the compiler is doing the counting and not me.

Comment: @Jens: yes, actually that's the motivation why everybody just uses the last syntax you mentioned and never look back. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of your fist `printf` is not predictable specifically because you failed to include the terminating zero character. If it appears to work in your experiment, it is only because by a random chance the next byte in memory happened to be zero and worked as a zero terminator. The chances of this happening depend greatly on where you declare your `name` array (it is not clear form your example). For a static array the chances might be pretty high, while for a local (automatic) array you'll run into various garbage being printed pretty often.

Comment: Essentially if I want to use the %s conversion I have to add a null zero "to be sure" the string is terminating properly?

Comment: Yes (this holds true in general whenever you want to use a `char` array as a C string); but it's much easier to use the special string initialization syntax (`char name[]="abcdef";`, where the `NUL` is added automatically, as well as the array size) instead of specifying the single characters like that.

Answer (score 5):

You're just being lucky; probably after the end of that array, on the stack, there's a zero, so `printf` stops reading just after the last character. If your program is very short and that zone of stack is still "unexplored" - i.e. the stack hasn't grown yet up to that point - it's very easy that it's zero, since generally modern OSes give initially zeroed pages to the applications.

More formally: by not having explicitly the `NUL` terminator, you're going in the land of undefined behavior, which means that anything can happen; such anything may also be that your program works fine, but it's just luck - and it's the worst type of bug, since, if it generally works fine, it's difficult to spot.

TL;DR version: don't do that. Stick to what is guaranteed to work and you won't introduce sneaky bugs in your application.

Answer (score 2):

You **must** include the null character at the end.

It worked without error because of luck, and luck alone. Try this:

```
char name[6] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
printf("%s",name);
printf("%d",name[6]);
```

You'll most probably see that you can read that memory, and that there's a zero in it. But it's sheer luck.

Comment: Actually, you are quite **un** lucky if your program "seems to work" when it does something bad like this, because that makes it harder to find the program. It will, of course, only blow up much later down the road, when you have written lots more (correct) code and now the problem seems to be somewhere completely different. Or it will "work" for you, and blow up when you show off your program to someone important. Or... you get the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

What most likely happened is that there happened to be the value of 0 at memory location name + 6.  This is not defined behavior though, you could get different output on a different system or with a different compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You do.  There are a few other ways to do it.

This form of initialization, puts the NUL character in for you automatically.

```
char name[7] = "abcdef";
printf("%s",name);
```

Note that I added 1 to the array size, to make space for that NUL.

One can also get away with omitting the size, and letting the compiler figure it out.

```
char name[] = "abcdef";
printf("%s",name);
```

Another method is to specify it with a pointer to a char.

```
char *name = "abcdef";
printf("%s",name);
```

Comment: I'd add that the last method you specified is not equivalent to the first two: in fact, the last one gets a pointer to a read-only region of memory where the literal `"abcdef"` is stored (and actually `name` should be a `const char *`), the other two initialize an array with that value, and such array can be modified without problems.

Comment: Yes, good point.  When I was a wee lad, you could modify them.